# Param assignment in Rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, parameter-passing

I am unfortunately running an application on Rails 2.3.18 and am seeing strange behavior with the params variable within the controllers. There are some areas of the app that (for some reason) assign params to itself or an empty hash by default. 
`params = (params || {})`
Now the params variable is initialized to be the request parameters so it should evaluate to true in a logical expression. However, in this case params gets set to {}. Why exactly is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Rails 2.3 app to play around with but `params` in a controller is actually method but saying `params = ...` creates a local variable that shadows the standard `params` method. For example, try this in `irb`:

```
def x
  puts 'x is being called'
  { :where_is => 'pancakes house?' }
end
x = x || { }
```

and you'll see that `x` is `{ }` and the `x` method never even gets called. The code that says:

```
params = (params || {})
```

is effectively doing this:

```
params = nil # Declare a local variable and initialize it to nil
params = params || { }
# -------^^^^^^ the local variable above, not the method
```

However, if you force the RHS `params` to be a method call:

```
params = params() || { }
# -------------^^
```

then it should call the method but you'll still have the local `params` variable on the LHS of the assignment.

I think you need to figure out why the code is doing `params = params || { }` and refactor it so that it isn't necessary. Are these controller methods trying to work when they're not actually in a controller? Are they depending on dodgy edge cases in older versions of Ruby? Was that code added cargo-cult style by someone copying mystery code from a blog they didn't understand?

Comment: It looks like this was indeed what was happening. I was not aware that methods need to be explicitly called in these types of scenarios. Thank you!